Why can file name not be shown for file upload using getValues from React-Hook-Form?
I want a file name to be shown when a file with correct file type and file size is uploaded.
const ACCEPT_FILE_TYPE_LIST = ["application/pdf", "image/gif", "image/jpeg", "image/png", "image/tiff"];

const [fileTypeError, setFileTypeError] = useState(false);
const [fileSizeError, setFileSizeError] = useState(false);

const {getValues, register, watch, formState: {errors} } = useForm({
    defaultValues: {certificate: null},
    mode: "onChange"
})

<FormControl error={!!errors.certificate}>
    <Box>
        <Button component="label" variant="contained" sx={{mr: 1}}>File Upload
            <input
                hidden
                type="file"
                {...register("certificate", {
                    required: "This field is required.",
                    validate: value => {
                        setFileTypeError(false);
                        setFileSizeError(false);
                        if (!ACCEPT_FILE_TYPE_LIST.includes(value[0].type)) {
                            setFileTypeError(true);
                            return "";
                        }
                        if (value[0].size > 10 * 1024 * 1024) {
                            setFileSizeError(true);
                            return "";
                        }
                        return true;
                    }
                })}
            />
        </Button>
        {!errors.certificate && <FormLabel>{getValues("certificate")?.[0].name}</FormLabel>}
    </Box>
    <FormHelperText error={fileTypeError}>Only pdf, gif, jpeg, png or tiff file is acceptable.</FormHelperText>
    <FormHelperText error={fileSizeError}>File size should be less than 10MB.</FormHelperText>
    <FormHelperText>{errors.certificate?.message}</FormHelperText>
</FormControl>

When using getValues("certificate"), if a file with correct file type and correct file size is selected, the file name can't be shown immediately. However, when the submit button is clicked (codes are not shown here), the file name is shown.
When using following codes, if a file with correct file type and correct file size is selected, the file name can be shown immediately.
const certificate = watch("certificate");

{!errors.certificate && <FormLabel>{certificate?.[0].name}</FormLabel>}

I've studied the react-hook-form documentation about getValues, it states "An optimized helper for reading form values. The difference between watch and getValues is that getValues will not trigger re-renders or subscribe to input changes.".
https://react-hook-form.com/docs/useform/getvalues
However, I don't understand how the statement explains the behaviour of getValues in my codes. Could someone please help explain?
Also, can my codes be further optimised? "Only pdf, gif, jpeg, png or tiff file is acceptable." and "File size should be less than 10MB." are always shown as helper texts in grey colour. When a file with incorrect file type is selected, "Only pdf, gif, jpeg, png or tiff file is acceptable." will be shown in red colour. When a file with incorrect file size is selected, "File size should be less than 10MB." will be shown in red colour. I don't know whether errors.certificate?.message can be applied to my cases and states of fileTypeError and fileSizeError can be removed.
